# How to cast time from date and time

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to extract only the time for the date time format that I currently have. So far this is the query that I have. I would like to only extract the time for the columns that I am creating (First_Arrival, Last_Arrival, etc.)

```
SELECT logon_id,activity_date
,MIN(CASE WHEN activity = 'AsnAssignmentOnSite_evt' THEN occurred END) First_Arrival
,MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'AsnAssignmentOnSite_evt' THEN occurred END) Last_Arrival
,MIN(CASE WHEN activity = 'OrdActivityComplete_evt' THEN occurred END) First_Completion
,MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'OrdActivityComplete_evt' THEN occurred END) Last_Completion
,MIN(CASE WHEN activity = 'AsnAssignmentEnRoute_evt' THEN occurred END) First_Enroute
,MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'AsnAssignmentEnRoute_evt' THEN occurred END) Last_Enroute
FROM activity
GROUP BY logon_id,activity_date
order by ACTIVITY_DATE
```

Comment: assumming SQL Server 2008+, then `CONVERT(TIME,occurred)` would do

Comment: always use tags to specify the version of your software

Comment: `cast(occurred as time)` using cast